# "Line 11 } expected" при написании класса

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Enumerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        enum Temperatures
        {
            FREEZING = 32,
            LUKEWARM = 65,
            ROOMTEMP = 72,
            HOT = 105,
            BOILING = 212
        }

            // constants are values that won't ever change during a program
            const int freezingPointDegF = 32;
            const int boilingPointDegF = 212;

            int myTemp = 65;

            if (myTemp > freezingPointDegF && myTemp < boilingPointDegF)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("At this temperature, water is a liquid");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Water is not a liquid at this temperature");
            }

            if (myTemp >= (int)Temperatures.FREEZING && myTemp <= (int)Temperatures.BOILING)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("At this temperature, water is a liquid");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Water is not a liquid at this temperature");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы объявили enum и константы внутри метода, чего делать нельзя. Вынесите объявление хотя бы за пределы метода Main.

Comment: спасибо помогло

Comment: Не за что. Не забывайте принимать ответ, чтобы тема считалась закрытой.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, константы можно оставить, а вот `enum` надо-таки вынести

Comment: @VladD, Вы правы, синтаксически можно, вот только на деле за всё время, что работаю, ни разу не использовал const на локальном уровне :)

Comment: @Spawn: тут вопрос семантики: имеют ли константы смысл лишь внутри данного метода, или они интересны всему классу?

Comment: вот так и отвечай людям с репутацией <0...